# Do I need a different admob banner id`s for different adviews?

Tags: android, admob

I have different adviews for banners on different activities. Do I need one admob id for all the adviews or do I need one foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with different ID's for each banner, it helps you identify highest traffic areas. You can make as many banner ID's as you need for your app.